# How do you turn off the postgresql trim function? I want to KEEP whitespace in db

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

I want to save text KEEPING whitespace, but postgresql automatically deletes whitespace with a built in trim function. I want to turn the trim function off. When I save text, I want to KEEP whitespace.

My table looks like this:

```
create table user_chapters( 
  chapter_id serial primary key, 
  chapter_content varchar)
```

I want chapter_content to keep the whitespace, but currently it is deleting all whitespace more than one. I want to be able to click the "tab" button to indent the first line of a paragraph. The html adds in whitespace to the p tag, but then postgresql deletes the whitespace.

Comment: Doesn't a `char()` datatype do what you want?

Comment: Are you asking about leading (prefix) or following (suffix) whitespace? Postgre should preserve both leading and following whitespace but will ignore following whitespace when performing text comparisons using most collations - this is an ISO SQL standards compliance rule. See: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/ec707a5ddf-postgres-varchar-and-silent-white-space-trimming

Comment: Please post the exact data-types of your table columns and the queries/statements you're using where you're seeing this auto-trim behaviour. `varchar` and `char` behave differently, for example.

Comment: My table looks like this:

create table user_chapters(
   chapter_id serial primary key, 
   chapter_content varchar)

I want chapter_content to keep the whitespace, but currently it is deleting all whitespace more than one. I want to be able to click the "tab" button to indent the first line of a paragraph. The html adds in whitespace to the <p> tag, but then postgresql deletes the whitespace.

Comment: Unclear. In case of HTML browser itself ignores whitespace, unless you use <pre> tags.

Comment: Postgres **will** keep the whitespace: https://rextester.com/KVBH6433 There is something in your code that removes it.

Comment: Arvo - thank you! It looks like that's the problem. When I inspected the html, it does in fact keep the whitespace. It's the html browser that is ignoring the whitespace.

Comment: @PageCOW The convention here is to keep Answers separate from Questions, even if you find the solution yourself. So rather than editing the question, you're encouraged to fill in the Answer box below.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks! Just made the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arvo answer: postgresql DOES store the whitespaces if you use varchar. It was my html browser that was automatically removing whitespace. You have to put the text within pre tags to keep the whitespace in your html.